# The USB ports do not work anymore on my RPI4

Tags: usb, pi-4, usb-hub

Since yesterday, the USB ports of my RPI4 do not work.

When I plug a usb device like a hard drive or a usb stick, I don't see any message about it in the logs and no new device in /dev.

When I type the command dmesg, I receive many times the following messages:

```
usb usb2-port3: over-current change #1602
usb usb2-port3: over-current condition
```

The above number 1602 is irrelevant because it increases like a counter and I receive the message for each port. I know these messages mean the power supply is insufficient to power a currently plugged usb device but I received them even if there is nothing plugged.

On my RPI 3 B+, I used to plug my external hard drives on a powered hub but on the RPI 4, I tried to plug the same HDD directly on the raspberry. Everything worked fine for weeks but some days ago I noticed my HDD crashed when I tried to copy a large file. Thus, I decided to use my powered hub again but the usb ports didn't work after that.

I give you some relevant information about my system:

uname -a

```
Linux Hostname 4.19.93-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 7 01:54:33 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

sudo lsusb -v (this command is very slow...)

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            4.19
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.19.93-1-ARCH xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:01:00.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             4
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0008.0080 C_OC 5Gbps SS.disabled
   Port 2: 0008.0080 C_OC 5Gbps SS.disabled
   Port 3: 0008.0080 C_OC 5Gbps SS.disabled
   Port 4: 0008.0080 C_OC 5Gbps SS.disabled
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000f
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         231 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2109 VIA Labs, Inc.
  idProduct          0x3431 Hub
  bcdDevice            4.20
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                1 USB2.0 Hub
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0001  1x 1 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             4
  wHubCharacteristic 0x00e0
    Ganged power switching
    Ganged overcurrent protection
    TT think time 32 FS bits
    Port indicators
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       50 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent    100 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0008.0000 C_OC
   Port 2: 0008.0000 C_OC
   Port 3: 0008.0000 C_OC
   Port 4: 0008.0000 C_OC
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x002a
  bNumDeviceCaps          3
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         231 micro seconds
  Container ID Device Capability:
    bLength                20
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      4
    bReserved               0
    ContainerID             {30eef35c-07d5-2549-b001-802d79434c30}
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            4.19
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.19.93-1-ARCH xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:01:00.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             1
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x02
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

I tried to downgrade the package raspberryrpi-firmware but it didn't change anything.

I guess it is a hardware issue or a firmware bug.

Comment: examine all of the USB connectors very carefully

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with erasing all the apps and data on your SD Card a simple format of the SD Card and loading of the OS should work.